# Foursquare venue photos API only occasionally working with client_id/client_secret?

Tags: foursquare

I've found that some venues will only return photos if I use a signed in user instead of a client_id / client_secret.  Is this intentional?

curl -i https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4c36476d93db0f47f6cc1d92/photos?client_id=xxx\&client_secret=xxx\&group=venue\&v=20120304

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 00:28:34 GMT
Expires: Mon, 5 Mar 2012 00:28:34 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/0.8.52
X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
Content-Length: 66
Connection: keep-alive

{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"photos":{"count":0,"items":[]}}}
```

curl -i https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/4c36476d93db0f47f6cc1d92/photos?group=venue\&v=20120304\&oauth_token=xxx\&v=20120304

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, private, no-store
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 05 Mar 2012 00:29:19 GMT
Expires: Mon, 5 Mar 2012 00:29:19 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/0.8.52
X-RateLimit-Limit: 1000
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 1000
Content-Length: 15311
Connection: keep-alive

{"meta":{"code":200},"notifications":[{"type":"notificationTray","item":{"unreadCount":0}}],"response":{"photos":{"count":14,"items":[lots of images here]}}}
```

I want to fetch a photo to associate with a given place as a background process, not tied to the specific user.  Is it intended that this API only functions correctly for signed in users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a bug in userless access to /venues/photos. The team is investigating. The intended behavior is that userless access of that endpoint returns all public photos attached to that venue.

Comment: Can you update this when it gets resolved?  For now, my traffic is low enough that I'm just funneling all these requests through my oauth_token, but I'd love to switch it back when it gets fixed.

Comment: Will do [+ padding to meet minimum comment length]

Comment: The fix for this will go out in the next few hours. Thanks for the bug report!