# Foursquare venue API: no results when using userless access via client_id

Tags: foursquare

I'm using the userless access to the Foursquare API using `client_id` and `client_secret`:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=37.789565,-122.395487&v=20120608&client_secret=XXX&client_id=YYY
```

And get a response, but no results:

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"response":{"venues":[]}}
```

The latitude and longitude are in SOMA in San Francisco, and there should be plenty of venues around it. And, in fact, when asking for the very same coordinates using an OAuth token  from the [API Explorer](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=users/self) instead of client_id and client_secret, I get plenty of results.

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=37.789565,-122.395487&v=20120608&oauth_token=XXX
```

However fact, when I change the location by a few blocks to `ll=37.779129,-122.393333` I get the same results for both queries, so there's nothing wrong with my `client_id` and `secret`. This is totally beyond my comprehension. Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of experimentation there seems to be a bug in the Foursquare API (@akdotcom if you can read this please confirm). So, basically asking for

```
37.789565,-122.395487
```

didn't return any venues, but

```
37.7895651,-122.395487
```

does. Trailing zeros do not help, however appending `0000001` to both latitude and longitude seemed to fix it for my test cases. I suppose it's some weird weird problem with their URL parsing, but maybe someone from foursquare could illuminate me.

Comment: Weird, when I type in your lat/lng pair, I get back valid results: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/explore#req=venues/search%3Fll%3D37.789565,-122.395487 -- are you still seeing this issue?

Comment: Funny, now it works (the issue was only with authentication over userless acess anyway) - I'll keep you updated if I find other coordinates for which it doesn't work. Could it be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560270/foursquare-venue-photos-api-only-occasionally-working-with-client-id-client-secr?rq=1 ?